# Allow anonymous access locally but not remotely with MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB server, which I have enabled auth on. I want to enable anonymous access (full read/write access) if someone tries to authenticate on my server locally (meaning if someone SSH into the server and write `mongo` or if an application uses `mongodb://localhost:27017/DATABASE`). If someone tries to authenticate from outside the network, it should not be allowed to, unless the person has an user (created using `db.createUser()`).

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid what you are looking to do is not possible (likely because it is a very poor security practice in general). There is a [Localhost Exception](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-users/#localhost-exception) which exists to allow the initial set up of auth etc. on a new server, but once you have auth set up (which you do), it no longer applies.

Comment: Yeah I figured that was the issue. I have actually just created an admin user and simply used the `?authenticateDatabase=admin` in my URI. Works just fine now :-)

Comment: I think suggesting that it is a "very poor security practice in general" is a bit presumptuous. Depending on the user's network security and how the machine is access, etc., it could be reasonable to assume that local non-auth'd access is properly secure.